# Accessing Earthquake Data

Tags: objective-c

I am making an app about earthquakes. I am using Objective-C in Xcode. I am trying to make a part of the app so that when an earthquake occurs and is reported on the USGS website, it will alert the user with an alarm if the location of the earthquake is at most 100 miles away from them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done but is all about how you want to implement. There are feeds offered by USGS, however you will likely want to setup a server to monitor or query these feeds every X minutes. Then when there is activity you will need to have logic to decide location of the user and if they are within the radius. There are different options and things to consider.

Developer information located at the bottom of this page - http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/